# Como Pasar el parámetro de un botón a otro Xamarin Forms

Tags: archivo, csv, botón, xamarin.forms, timestamp

Gracias por los comentarios, mejoré mi código como comentaste aunque me sale una excepción cuando le doy el botón saveEvento Unhandled Exception:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 31:17. Method 
BtnSaveEvento_Clicked does not have the correct signature
```

falta la parte de colocar la ruta del directorio que pueda contener el documento, ya que tengo la cadena adecuada con el formato de un csv

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;


using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace appRegistroAct
{

    public partial class PageRegistroActividades : ContentPage
    {
        DateTime startDate;
        DateTime endDate;

        public PageRegistroActividades (List<string> Param1, List<string> Param2)
        {

            InitializeComponent ();

            //var timeStampInicio = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            //var timeStampFin = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            picker_actor1.Title = "Selecciona un Actor";
            picker_activity.Title = "Selecciona una acción";
            picker_actor2.Title = "Selecciona un Actor";

            picker_actor1.ItemsSource = Param1;
            picker_activity.ItemsSource = Param2;
            picker_actor2.ItemsSource = Param1;
        }
        private async void Btn_GoBack(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            await Navigation.PopAsync();//Regresar
        }

        private void Btn_EventoInicio_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            startDate= DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void Btn_EventoFin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            endDate= DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void BtnSaveEvento_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args, string timeStampInicio, string timeStampFin, string actor1, string actor2)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("read_file.csv", $"{actor1},{actor2},{timeStampInicio},{timeStampFin}\n");
        }
    }
}

//De acuerdo con la documentación debo agregar esto, supongo que debe ser en otra clase y mandarla llamar desde el método saveEventoClicked
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (SaveAndLoad))]
    namespace WorkingWithFiles {
        public class SaveAndLoad : ISaveAndLoad {
            public void SaveText (string filename, string text) {
                var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                var filePath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, filename);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText (filePath, text);
        }
            public string LoadText (string filename) {
                var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                var filePath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, filename);
                return System.IO.File.ReadAllText (filePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas mezclando varias preguntas en la misma y no tienes muy claro tampoco como tienes las cosas.

En mi opinión no tiene sentido que los métodos de click tengan retorno. Tu llamas a un click y se lanza un evento que hace una cosa. Si lo que quieres es mostrarlo en pantalla tienes que asignar la fecha a un objeto visual, pero entiendo que no es así.

Respecto al como pasar el parámetro de un sitio a otro es tan sencillo como hacer:

```
DateTime startDate;
DateTime endDate;

private void Btn_EventoInicio_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    startDate= DateTime.Now;
    //pintar el valor en pantalla
}

private void Btn_EventoFin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    endDate= DateTime.Now;
    //pintar el valor en pantalla
}

private void BtnSaveEvento_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // lo ideal seria que tuviera alguna forma de activar este botón solo si ya se han pulsado los otros antes.
    if(startDate!=null && endDate!=null) 
    {        
            //si es timestamp deberias usar startDate.Ticks; y endDate.Ticks;
            var timeStampInicio = startDate.ToString();
            var timeStampFin = endDate.ToString();
    }
    //haz lo que quieras con esos datos
}
```

Después de eso ya tienes dos temas diferentes, uno es como hacer un CSV y el otro es como grabarlo en el teléfono.

Para guardar el fichero el fichero en Csv tienes que ver de buscar alguna librería. Yo he usado [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), pero solo en proyectos de Xamarin classic para android.

Por las tags que tienes intuyo que tu app es Xamarin.Forms y la estas haciendo para android e iOS. La forma y el sitio donde se guardan los ficheros es diferente en cada plataforma puedes encontrar la información [aqui](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Loading_and_Saving_Files)